# iOS TCP client on localhost

Tags: ios

I'm looking to setup a TCP client on **localhost** on iOS. 
I'm using *GCDAsyncSocket* but I get NSPOSIXErrorDomain errors:

- Code=61 "Connection refused" or
- Code=49 "Can't assign requested
  address"

Implementation:

```
asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
uint aPort = (arc4random() % 1000) + 1024;
NSError *err = nil;
if (![asyncSocket connectToHost:@"localhost" onPort:aPort withTimeout:-1 error:&err])
{
    NSLog(@"Client setup error on port:%u %@", aPort, err);
}
```

Delegate:

```
-(void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err
{
    NSLog(@"Client socketDidDisconnect");
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"ClientRelay socket error: %@", err);
    }
}
```

Can this be done on localhost?

Comment: you are trying to connect a server on a random port. how is that suppose to work?

Comment: aside from the random port issue, try just use 127.0.0.1, ive done it before using that, never tried 'localhost' before but it might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done on localhost. However you have some misconceptions about ports.

Ports - To make a connection to a server you need its IP Address and port number. Port numbers are the way the IP Protocol determines which packet goes to which application to deliver to. Using a random port thus will not work.

Connect to localhost using GCDAsycSocket

1. Create a new instance of GCDAsycSocket
2. Call `- (BOOL)connectToHost:(NSString *)host onPort:(uint16_t)port error:(NSError **)errPtr;` with the host parameter as `@"localhost"` to start accepting connections.For the port, use a number that is more than 6000.
3. Create a new instance GCDAsycSocket
4. Call `- (BOOL)connectToHost:(NSString *)host onPort:(uint16_t)port error:(NSError **)errPtr;` with host as `@"localhost"` and port as the port you chose in step 2.
5. You should be able to connect.